# File Management Section for an Admin Panel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, cloud-storage

I'm developing a CRM Web Application for my client. It includes client management, payments and so on.

The technologies I use:

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- EntityFramework 6
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Bootstrap 3

Now my client wants to add a cloud file storage like Dropbox to the Web Application. It should allow uploading / removing files and folders (for admins) and regular users should be allowed to download them.

I think there are some good complete solutions for that so I don't reinvent the wheel. Opensource and Free ones are preferred. I'm looking for a module that I could just set up and add to my existing application.

---

**UPDATE**

I think SO community got me wrong. I'm not looking for a really heavy file management solution. What is needed is something like Masoud Bimar suggested. But I'm looking for something even smaller and simpler.

I just don't want to reinvent the wheel and it's kind of boring for me to code this from scratch.

I'm sure somebody already developed this functionality.

Again, a solution should just allow to:

- Upload a file to a local folder
- Delete files from the local folder
- Create folders in the local folder
- Delete folders in the local folder

My client will use it occasionally and will upload no more than just 20 files. Maybe delete them and upload new time to time. That's it.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: Not to disagree with you @Selvin, but where should he go to get such? Which of the other "stack sites" can he use to solicit help? Perhaps he can be directed to he doesn't come back here with this or a similar question.

Comment: @Eniola - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is off topic as well, SO should be to ask technical questions, not business questions. You asked about dropbox, you can find an answer about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522682/using-dropbox-in-mvc-4

Comment: @ZakkDiaz The question is technical. I'm not asking about any business. The only thing I want to do is to find a piece of code which will have a nice UI and allow to upload files to a folder on the server where the ASP.NET MVC app resides.

Comment: @Isma I know what Amazon S3 is and this is not what is needed. The thing I need is a simple file management code which will allow to upload a couple of files and store them locally on the server. I just don't want to write it myself since I think it is not a rocket science code and someone already has developed it.

Comment: @kseen, ok, got it, I posted an answer with an example of how to store files locally on the server. Hope it helps.

Comment: So did Isma solve your issue? Give him credit if he did. If it's not rocket science though then don't waste a professional engineers time with something that's below your time.

Comment: @Isma Thanks Isma! Accepted your answer as it was the closest to what I've was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple file management system using standard ASP.NET MVC controllers and actions, entity framework and the awesome javascript library [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload multiple files using AJAX.

Each customer will have a list of files so we need to store this information in a database table, here is the model:

```
public class FileUpload
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string OriginalFilename { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Then, a controller will handle file uploads and downloads, etc...

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    private SomeDbContext db = new SomeDbContext();

    // You should store the following settings in your Web.config or in your DB, I just put them here for demo purposes

    // This is the root folder where your files will be saved
    private string FilesRoot = @"c:\temp";

    // Accepted file types and maximum size, for security (it should match the settings in your view)
    private string[] AcceptedFiles = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".doc" };
    private int MaxFileSizeMB = 10;

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(int customerId)
    {
        foreach(string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var upload = Request.Files[file];

            if (!ValidateUpload(upload))
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

            string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);

            // Save the file in FilesRoot/{CustomerId}/{GUID}
            string savePath = Path.Combine(FilesRoot, customerId.ToString());
            if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
            }

            upload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(savePath, filename));

            // Save file info to database
            var fileUpload = new FileUploadModel()
            {
                CustomerId = customerId,
                Filename = filename,
                OriginalFilename = upload.FileName,
                ContentType = upload.ContentType
            };

            db.FileUploads.Add(fileUpload);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private bool ValidateUpload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (!AcceptedFiles.Contains(Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName)))
            return false;
        else if (upload.ContentLength > MaxFileSizeMB * 1048576)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
    {
        var fileUpload = db.FileUploads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (fileUpload == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        string path = Path.Combine(FilesRoot, fileUpload.CustomerId.ToString(), fileUpload.Filename);

        byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        return File(fileContents, fileUpload.ContentType, fileUpload.OriginalFilename);
    }

    public ActionResult ListFiles(int customerId)
    {
        var files = db.FileUploads.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
        return View(files.ToList());
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the view to upload files, you will probably need to add another view to show the list of files for a given customer but that should be straight forward.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload Files";
}

<div>
    <button id="selectFile">Click to Browse File</button>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "uploadForm", @class = "dropzone dropzone-area" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.Hidden("CustomerId", 1)

    <div class="dz-message">Drop File Here To Upload</div>

    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dropzone.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.options.selectForm = {
            paramName: 'file',
            maxFilesize: 10,
            maxFiles: 10,
            acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.png,.doc,.pdf',
            addRemoveLinks: false
        };

        $('#selectFile').on('click', function () {
            $('#uploadForm').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Really reinventing the wheel is tricky, however using 3rd party packages will always have a limitation.

I use a Bucket S3 in Amazon Web Services and as access to the files is through credentials you can limit access to the file easily by writing to the database when uploading the users who have the access.

Here is an example of upload and download code.

You will need to install the AWS SDK Nuget package.

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

Link with explanation for creating credentials

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-setup.html#net-dg-signup

I hope this can help in some way

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
    IAmazonS3 clientAws = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
    string urlTemp = Path.GetTempFileName();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    string nameFile = guid + extension;
    string contentType = file.ContentType;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(urlTemp, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    try
    {
        // simple object put
        using (clientAws)
        {
            var request = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = "yourbucket",
                Key = nameFile,
                FilePath = urlTemp,
                ContentType = contentType
            };
            var response = await clientAws.PutObjectAsync(request);

            //write in your db
        }
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
        if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
            (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") ||
            amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
            Console.WriteLine("If you haven't signed up for Amazon S3, please visit http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred with the message '{0}' when writing an object", amazonS3Exception.Message);
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string file)
{
    try
    {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
        IAmazonS3 clientAws = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);

        GetObjectResponse response = new GetObjectResponse();

        string urlTemp = Path.GetTempPath();
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string nameFile = guid + ".pdf";

        try
        {
            // simple object put
            using (clientAws)
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();

                request.BucketName = "yourBucket";
                request.Key = file;
                response = await clientAws.GetObjectAsync(request);
                CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = source.Token;
                await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(urlTemp + nameFile, true, token);


                var path = urlTemp + nameFile;
                var memory = new MemoryStream();
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                }
                memory.Position = 0;

                var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(memory, "application/pdf");
                return fsResult;

            }

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") ||
                amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                Console.WriteLine("If you haven't signed up for Amazon S3, please visit http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred with the message '{0}' when writing an object", amazonS3Exception.Message);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Amazon S3 is really overkilling here. I'm looking for a simple local solution that will allow managing files and folders in some folder which is considered as the root folder.

Comment: Okay, I hope I have helped some future project.

Comment: This is why your question is off topic. You aren't willing to do the work your self but are asking others to do it. When someone gives you a competent solution you don't accept it. This isn't about fixing your problem, it's about growing our knowledge base as a community.

Answer (score 0):

I Used This One, Built with elFinder Library.

File Manager, With ELFinder.Net.
support Directories, PDF Files, Permissions, Nice UI.

I was Completely satisfied with it.

Packages Info:

```
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

[github repository](https://github.com/Rahim373/File-Manager-In-MVC-With-elFinder)